Doubts on the proof of the divergence of harmonic series

So i was reading the above proof on the divergence of harmonic series, one thing that is frustrating me is that why we can conclude anything after the inequality equals to S as well. For isn't it a very different series than the original format, like a_1 = 1/2, a_2 = 1/2, while the original starts with 1 then 1/2 then 1/3 and goes on which makes a big different when its come to the partial sum. For example the s_3 in the original form = 1+1/2+1/3 while after the inequality it equates to 1/2 +1/2+1/4
Sorry for the messy format, for i am so new to the syntax.

It's a proof by contradiction: assume the harmonic series converges to some finite number S. Then all of those manipulations are valid for convergent sums. Of course, since we obtain that S > S, our original assumption was mistaken: the harmonic series does not converge.

Yep I understand which this is a contradiction proof, I am just wondering how it reaches such conclusion by algebra from the third line to the last line

Specifically why can we say that the third line equates to the "existed" sum of the harmonic Series

For afterall isn't It a very different sequence/series after the inequality sign with a_1 = 1/2 instead of 1 and so on

We suppose the harmonic series converges. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S}&=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}\right)+\cdots\tag{1}\\
&\color{blue}{>}\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}_{=1}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)}_{=\frac{1}{2}}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\right)}_{=\frac{1}{3}}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\right)}_{=\frac{1}{4}}+\cdots\tag{2}\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\tag{3}\\
&=\color{blue}{S}
\end{align*}
and get the contradiction $\color{blue}{S>S}$.
Comment:

In (1) we note that since the series $S$ is convergent we can put parentheses which does not change the convergence behavior of the series. The series $S$ is defined as the sequence of its partial sums and setting parentheses implies we consider a subsequence of this sequence of partial sums which converges to the same value as $S$.

In (2), we perform estimates of the form $\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)>\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$, which is obvious.

In (3) we have at first to evaluate the expressions in the parentheses giving us $S$ again.



Thank your for sharing. Would you mind to help with some additional clarification. Although I understand which you can group things and that after grouping, It will be similar to the original series. But isn't the "speed" of convergence is different for each term or isn't this two different series. For a_1 and a_2 now both equate to 1/2 instead of 1 and 1/2. If that is the case then it is not guaranteed that is S again?

@StephenJohson: Die expressions in (2) and (3) are identical. In both cases we have $a_1=1=(1/2+1/2)$.
